# data wont display in view with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

First time using php and code igniter , the data I want to display wont show up in the textfield, Did I miss something with the codes?

View

```
    Username: <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="" disabled="disable" value="<?php echo $result['username']; ?>" > <br>
    Password: <input type="text" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder=""disabled="disable" value="<?php echo $result['password']; ?>"><br>
    Rank : <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rank" name="rank" placeholder=""disabled="disable" value="<?php echo $result['title']; ?>"><br>
```

Model

```
    Class profile_model extends CI_Model {
     public function my_data()
   {

    $username = $this->session->userdata('$username');
    $data = array();
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('user');
     $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $query = $this->db->get();

   //this will return multiple rows or object of arrays
   //return $query->result();
   // you need to send only single row
    return $query->row();
  }


 }
```

Controller

```
    public function profile() {
    // in data array key name should be same which you will pass to view    

    $this->load->model('profile_model');
    $data['result'] = $this->profile_model->my_data();        
    $this->load->view('profile_view', $data);


}

}
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUoew.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no need to use `$data=array()` in your model function because `$query->row();` returns object and use the following function instead of you have written in your model:

```
public function my_data()
{
$username = $this->session->userdata('$username');    
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('user');
$this->db->where('username', $username);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->row();
}
```

and write the following code in view:

```
value="<?php echo $result->username; ?>"
```

Answer (score 0):

`$query->row()` returns an object, not an array.  Try this instead, in your view:

```
value="<?php echo $result->username; ?>"
```

Comment: I got an Error it says Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Are you sure your model method is actually finding any query matches?  You should probably check `if($query->num_rows() > 0) { ... }`

Comment: in my model `$data = array();`
in controller `$data['result'] = $this->profile_model->my_data();`

Answer (score 0):

Try This use row_array()

```
 public function my_data()
  {
     $username = $this->session->userdata('$username');
     $data = array();
     $this->db->select('*');
     $this->db->from('user');
     $this->db->where('username', $username);
     $query = $this->db->get();
     return $query->row_array();
   }
```